# Override Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring-security

Spring Boot Security,

My Application is already running using Spring Security. Now I want to authenticate the users through OAuth. Is there any way to build a custom servlet to achieve this?

Comment: And why don't you want to use Spring Security for this purpose?

Comment: Is it possible to add one more authentication provider along with the existing mechanism?

Comment: Yes Please read the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new Filter to intercept and authenticate OAuth requests in which it should call the authenticationManager.authenticate method and save the result of the authentication token in the SecurityContextHolder. This way the user is fully authenticated.

Note, that this way you don't "override" or "bypass" the Spring Security.  You just use it to perform a different authentication.